# Evaluating the output of a program as an integer

Tags: linux

I'm trying to create a script that will evaluate the output of a command line, and then print if it's larger than 200.

The program `/exc/list` will count the number of "stories" I have in a directory as an expression. For example:

```
/exc/list q show.today1.rundown
```

will return 161 if there are 161 stories in the today1 rundown.

I have to figure this for 23 different directories. If the number of stories is greater than 200, I need it to print it to a temp file (`/tmp/StoryCount.$date`).

What's the best method to handle this comparison?

Comment: Note, you didn't say what language you're using for your script.  Is it **bash**?

Comment: Sorry, it is in bash.

Comment: NP, that's what I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **bash**, variables are essentially all strings (or arrays of strings).  But the **[ ]** and **[[ ]]** command(s) have several operators that treat the arguments as integers:  **-lt -le -eq -ne -ge -gt**

So, you could use:

```
for dir in ${LIST_OF_DIRECTORIES}; do
  if [[ $(/exc/list q ${dir}) -gt 200 ]]; then
    echo "${dir}"
  fi
done > /tmp/StoryCount.$(date +%y%m%d)
```

Note that if any directory name has whitespace, then this won't work as-is.

Also, the other answers use `&&` rather than an explicit `if` for the conditional.  They function the same for single statements and I tend to use `&&` for my own scripts, but depending on who will be maintaining the script I tend to be more verbose/explicit.

Comment: Actually, `[[` supports using `>` instead of `-gt`. You only need `-gt` if you're using `[` because `>` would be interpreted as a redirection.

Comment: But that's a lexical sort - **[[ 30 > 200 ]]** returns true.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking of `((...))`.

Comment: Thanks for the great help in this! It worked wonderfully, though I'm now feeling a bit clunky.

I can't get a list of directories to work for some reason, so I've once again ended up listing them all one by one:

`if [[ $(/exc/list q show.today1.rundown|wc -l) -gt 200 ]]; then
echo "Caution: Today1 rundown has "$(/exc/list q show.today1.rundown|wc -l)" stories in it. Check it out." > /tmp/StoryCount.$date
fi`

Any thoughts?

Comment: According to your OP the **/exc/list q DIRNAME** should print a number.  Sorry, but I don't know that tool. My only advice is perhaps replace **q** with another flag? But I doubt this forum will be the best place to ask about that tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
num=$(/exc/list q show.today1.rundown) #store command output in num
#sanitize num so the comparison doesn't break:
num=${num//\.[0-9]/} #remove numbers after a decimal point
num=${num//[^0-9]/} #remove any non-digit character
#if num is greater than 200 print it to a temporary file:
[ "$num" -gt 200 ] && printf "%d\n" "$num" > "/tmp/StoryCount.$(date)"
```

This of course assumes that `num` can never be negative; which is reasonably safe if you're using it to count something.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your 23 directories in an array in bash like so:

```
$ dirs=(show.today1.rundown show.today2.rundown)

-or-

$ dirs=(\
show.today1.rundown \
show.today2.rundown \
)
```

Then loop through them like so:

```
$ for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do echo "$dir";done
show.today1.rundown
show.today2.rundown
```

You could then incorporate the `/exc/list` command inside the for loop like so:

```
dateStamp=$(date +"%F_%T")

for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do

  cnt=$(/exc/list q $dir)  
  [ "$cnt" -gt 200 ] && printf "%d\n" "$cnt"

done | tee "/tmp/StoryCount.$dateStamp"
```